# calling afterSaveCommit in link() call

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

When I link belongs-to-many entities through a junction table with the belongsToMany->link() function, the afterSaveCommit event on the junction table doesn't fire. The link() function appears to always call save() within a transaction, and I can't find where it would call afterSaveCommit, since there is no toplevel save() call from an entity.

Is this an oversight or by design?

Answer (score 0):

After stepping through the code multiple times, and dwelling on it, I think the question of what it "should" be has arguments on both sides.

I'm posting my solution in the hopes it'll help someone else.

I am keeping a denormalized copy of logical records in an ElasticSearch repository for analysis, and the goal is to automatically sync ES when any of the participating relational entities change. All of the relevant entities hooked the afterSave trigger to sync ES. The core logical record has a lot of belongsToMany relationships with lists of static data, so lots of join tables and calls to link(). The ES record was being updated after each one, which was taking an inordinate amount of time.

I resorted to the afterSave event, which is always triggered, and then creating a behavior placed on all relevant tables with the following code, which depends upon the behavior of the option _primary being set to true when the toplevel entity is being saved. Indeed, this is one of the clues Cake uses to determine when to trigger the afterSaveCommit event.

I do have concerns about using an undocumented underscore-prefixed flag, even if it is being passed back in an options array.

```
class ElasticSyncBehavior extends Behavior
{   
    private static $_suspend_flag = false;

public function suspend_elastic_sync() {
    self::$_suspend_flag = true;
}

public function resume_elastic_sync() {
    self::$_suspend_flag = false;
}

public function afterSave($event, $entity, $options) {
    if($options["_primary"]!=true || self::$_suspend_flag==true) {
        return $entity;
    }

    // do synchronization here

    return $entity;
}
public function afterDelete(Event $event, EntityInterface $entity, ArrayObject $options) {
    if($options["_primary"]!=true || self::$_suspend_flag==true) {
        return $entity;
    }

    // do synchronization here

    return $entity;
}
}
```

This forces the same behavior, where the synchronization is only done after the top entity is saved, which in the link() case, is the join table.

I also added the delete event in there, both to handle unlink() calls as well as cascading deletes.

I also put in a safeguard hack to override the behavior altogether if that's what's desired. Making it a static var on the behavior allows it to be shared across all entities that have the behavior, even though they each have their own event manager.